# NHibernate under SharePoint 2010

Tags: nhibernate, sharepoint

I am having trouble getting NHibernate up and running under SharePoint 2010.

My config code works as I have an integration test project running fine.

The problem is to do with gac assemblies and NHibernate references resulting in this error:

```
[FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'NHibernate.ByteCode.Castle' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.]
   System.Reflection.Assembly._nLoad(AssemblyName fileName, String codeBase, Evidence assemblySecurity, Assembly locationHint, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection) +0
   System.Reflection.Assembly.InternalLoad(AssemblyName assemblyRef, Evidence assemblySecurity, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, Boolean forIntrospection) +416
   System.Reflection.Assembly.InternalLoad(String assemblyString, Evidence assemblySecurity, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, Boolean forIntrospection) +166
   System.Reflection.Assembly.Load(String assemblyString) +35
   NHibernate.Util.ReflectHelper.TypeFromAssembly(AssemblyQualifiedTypeName name, Boolean throwOnError) +641
   NHibernate.Bytecode.AbstractBytecodeProvider.SetProxyFactoryFactory(String typeName) +67

[UnableToLoadProxyFactoryFactoryException: Unable to load type 'NHibernate.ByteCode.Castle.ProxyFactoryFactory, NHibernate.ByteCode.Castle' during configuration of proxy factory class.
Possible causes are:
- The NHibernate.Bytecode provider assembly was not deployed.
- The typeName used to initialize the 'proxyfactory.factory_class' property of the session-factory section is not well formed.

Solution:
Confirm that your deployment folder contains one of the following assemblies:
NHibernate.ByteCode.LinFu.dll
NHibernate.ByteCode.Castle.dll]
   NHibernate.Bytecode.AbstractBytecodeProvider.SetProxyFactoryFactory(String typeName) +336
   NHibernate.Cfg.Configuration.ConfigureProxyFactoryFactory() +179
   NHibernate.Cfg.Configuration.BuildSessionFactory() +23
   FluentNHibernate.Cfg.FluentConfiguration.BuildSessionFactory() +50
```

FYI, NHibernate.ByteCode.Castle is registered in the gac. I also have these two item in web.config:

```
 <compilation batch="false" debug="true">
      <assemblies>
         <add assembly="NHibernate.ByteCode.Castle, Version=3.1.0.4000, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=aa95f207798dfdb4" />
         ....

&

<runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
       <qualifyAssembly partialName="NHibernate.ByteCode.Castle, Version=3.1.0.4000, Culture=neutral" fullName="NHibernate.ByteCode.Castle, Version=3.1.0.4000, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=aa95f207798dfdb4" />
      ...
```

Any clues as to the extra wiring required?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this was the key bit, not specifying culture or version in the partialName:

```
<qualifyAssembly partialName="NHibernate.ByteCode.Castle" fullName="NHibernate.ByteCode.Castle, Version=3.1.0.4000, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=aa95f207798dfdb4" />
```

did the trick

Answer (score 0):

The "or one of its dependencies" remark might be worth further investigation. Get [Dependency Walker](http://www.dependencywalker.com/) and check whether NHibernate.ByteCode.Castle.dll depends on anything else, and if it does, whether it's in the GAC or not.